# npm package to ssh to a server without password nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using ssh2 package to ssh to a server. 
By default when I connect to the server from cmd line, I don't have to pass in the password as we have ssh keys shared. 
I connect at ssh abcuser@server and I am automatically connected.
But using ssh2, if I dont give password, it complains saying - Error: All configured authentication methods failed

Below is my code-

```
conn.exec(request.scriptName, function(err, stream) {
                if(err){
                    logger.error('Failed to execute via ssh. ERROR: '+ err);
                    logger.exitAfterFlush(1);
                }
                stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
                   conn.end();
                }).on('data', function(data) {
                    let outputJson = JSON.parse(data.toString());
                    logger.info('Task Succeeded', {'output':outputJson});
                    logger.exitAfterFlush(0);
                }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
                    let details = {'details':data.toString()};
                    logger.error('Task Failed',{'output':details});
                    logger.exitAfterFlush(1);
                });
            });
        }).connect({
            host: request.hostName,
            port: 22,
            username: abcuser
        });
```

Can anyone suggest how I can resolve this?

Comment: Just configure your ssh to use public keys

Comment: Just do this `var pubKey = utils.genPublicKey(utils.parseKey(fs.readFileSync('user.pub')));`, and utils is a part of ssh2 `const utils = ssh2.utils;`